# Data structure for expressing the traffic condition of a road in game

Tags: java, oop, data-structures, racing

I want to design a data structure with OOP for emulating traffic situation in a racing game.
The requirements are as below:

> 1. Each vehicle can know on which position of a lane, which lane, and which section of road it is driving.
> 2. For each road, it can know how many vehicles are on it, and how many vehicles on each lane on the road.
> 3. (plus) Each vehicle has it's driving strategy. For example, some vehicles like to drive fast while others like slow.

I use java to implement this topic. Currently my objects are as below. I just know that this could need a bi-direction relationship between `Vehicle` and `Road`/`RoadSection`, but I don't know how to implement it.

```
class Lane {
    List<Vehicle> vehicleDrivingOnMe = new ArrayList<Vehicle>()

}

class RoadSection {

    int roadSectionLengthByKM
    /**
     * Integer: LaneID, example: 0 for overspeed
     */
    Map<Integer, Lane> lanes = new HashMap<Integer, Lane>()
}

class Road {
    List<RoadSection> roadSectionList = new ArrayList<RoadSection>()
}

class Vehicle {
    int drivingSpeedByKM

}
```

Then, my problem is, what elements should I add into what object for fulfilling the requirements 1 and 2? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To fulfill requirement 1 you can maintain parent pointers.

```
class Lane {
    RoadSection roadSection;
    List<Vehicle> vehicleDrivingOnMe = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();

    public void addVehicle(Vehicle vehicle) {
        //Update parent
        vehicle.lane = this;
        //Update the position
        vehicle.position = vehicleDrivingOnMe.size();
        vehicleDrivingOnMe.add(vehicle);
    }
}

class Vehicle {
    Lane lane;
    int drivingSpeedByKM;
    int position;
}
```

You can now get the lane of a vehicle by `vehicle.lane.roadSection`. Just update the parent pointers accordingly.

To fulfill requirement 2 you can either implement just in time calculation or cache the results in a field for objects up in the hierarchy. Like `noOfVechiles`. For just in time calculation you can look for something like this.

```
class Road {
    List<RoadSection> roadSectionList = new ArrayList<RoadSection>();

    public long getVehicles() {
        long count = 0;
        for (RoadSection section : roadSectionList) {
            for (Integer laneId : section.lanes.keySet()) {
                count += section.lanes.get(laneId).vehicleDrivingOnMe.size();
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public long getVehicles(int laneId) {
        long count = 0;
        for (RoadSection section : roadSectionList) {
            Lane lane = section.lanes.get(laneId);
            count += lane == null ? 0 : lane.vehicleDrivingOnMe.size();
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```